# How to deal with quoted and unquotes strings when executing it in command prompt?

Tags: string, go

```golang
input comes from an JSON request which looks like

{ 
   "inputString" : "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\" x c:\\temp\\test.zip -oc:\\temp\\test" 
}

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    //Input received will be of this format
    var inputstring string = "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe\" x c:\temp\firmware8.zip -oc:\temp\fw"

    cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", inputstring)

    out, err := cmd.Output()

    fmt.Println("doneee", string(out), "err", err)
}
```

Output : **"'\"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe\

"'** is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"** x c:\temp\test.zip -oc:\temp\test - I have to run this command on command prompt but it is just executing the part which is highlighted

As the input string is not static (it comes from a JSON),So we cannot split them into arguments

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var inputstring string = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\" x c:\\temp\\firmware8.zip -oc:\\temp\\fw"
var buf, stderr bytes.Buffer
*proc := exec.Command("cmd")
proc.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{CmdLine: fmt.Sprintf(`/c "%s"`, inputstring)}* //Adding this line helped to add the cmd as single line

proc.Stderr = &stderr
proc.Stdout = &buf
proc.Start()
time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
fmt.Println("doneee", buf.String(), "error is ", stderr.String())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw string. look [this tutorial](https://www.golangprograms.com/golang-raw-string-literals-and-interpreted-string-literals.html).

```go
var inputstring string = `"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" x c:\temp\test.zip -oc:\temp\test`
```

Comment: should it be double or single backslashes?

Comment: Thanks for your point, yes It's should be single backslashes

Comment: @S4eed3sm, It is a json input

{

"inputString":"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\" x c:\\temp\\test.zip -oc:\\temp\\test"

}

We can't add back tick to the string it comes as string

I tried strconv.quote and strconv.unquote nothing works

Comment: You must edit your question. lets think about this problem.